# Approximate search in Google App engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am currently working on a solution for searching brand names, so far we have about 10M different brands and we are using Google Cloud Search API. We are currently indexing the 3-grams for each brand name, getting an user query and again extracting the 3-grams, then we search for documents containing all the 3-grams.

What we would like to do is to find not only documents having all 3-grams but also documents having at least one and sorting the results by the number of matches. Would it be possible to do that using the Google Cloud Search API? Or should I be looking into something like Elastic Search?

Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone on a similar situation we ended up using Elastic Search and it has proven to be a lot more flexible than Google Full Text Search.

And even thought searching for a limited amount of N-grams was not possible Elastic allows edit distance queries which helped us to find misspellings and similar words which was essential in our use case.

We also noticed a great improvement on the search speed and specially on indexing.